# Is there a way to pass an object's field implicitly to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Suppose I have an object

```
class Obj {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

And an array of objects

```
Obj o[N];
```

I want to copy each Obj.a into an int array and I know other languages allow me to make a function that might look like this in C++

```
int & fun(Obj os[], T key, int N){
    int a[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
       a[i] = os[i].key;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Is there any reusable way to do this in C++? For reference, Obj's code can't be modified.

Comment: Yes there is! Don't use a C-style array and everything gonna be fine!

Comment: Returning `a` by reference is UB. Do you need to be able to edit those members?

Comment: @mash you probably misread the question (unless it's irony?)

Comment: @mash Even if you use `std::vector`, that doesn't solve the problem. The question is the same.

Comment: @mash I meant the whole stenence :) I had same doubts as Melpomene :)

Comment: Look at those answers. They pass `size_t N` -.-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the `std::transform` function is for. All you need to provide is a function to get the desired element from an `Obj`. This example shows how to do it with [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>    
#include <iostream>

struct Obj { int a, b, c; };

int main() {

    Obj o[3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {11, 22, 33},{111, 222, 333}};

    int a[3];

    std::transform(std::begin(o), std::end(o),
                   std::begin(a),
                   std::mem_fn(&Obj::a));

    for (auto e : a)
        std::cout << e << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

Output:

> 1 11 111

This can all be wrapped up in a helper function to allow the caller to set the attribute to extract. But note if you really want a function to return an array, you'll need to use a copyable type such as `std::array` or `std::vector`. In C++ plain arrays are not copyable so can't be returned by value from a function.

Comment: An alternative to `[](const Obj& e) { return e.a;}` could be `std::mem_fn(&Obj::a);` which involves fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::size_t;

struct Obj {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

static void fun(const Obj *os, size_t N, int Obj::*const key) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << os[i].*key << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    Obj o[] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
    fun(o, sizeof o / sizeof o[0], &Obj::b);
}
```

I changed the return type of `fun` because your version doesn't typecheck. For demonstration purposes `fun` simply outputs the elements.

The key here is that you can abstract over class fields by using [member pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You could template the fun function to make it work with various types.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pointer-to-member syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Obj {
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::unique_ptr<int[]>
fn(Obj* os, size_t N, int Obj::*member)
{
    auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = os[i].*member;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    Obj os[] { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 } };

    auto a1 = fn(os, 2, &Obj::a);
    auto a2 = fn(os, 2, &Obj::b);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << a1[i] << ", " << a2[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/cQMyh3

Or you could use a lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Obj {
    int a;
    int b;
};

std::unique_ptr<int[]>
fn(Obj* os, size_t N, std::function<int(const Obj&)> keyFn)
{
    auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = keyFn(os[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    Obj os[] { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 } };

    auto a1 = fn(os, 2, [](const Obj& o){ return o.a; });
    auto a2 = fn(os, 2, [](const Obj& o){ return o.b; });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << a1[i] << ", " << a2[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/9OvTzl

Or the more generic:

```
template<typename KeyFn>
std::unique_ptr<int[]>
fn(Obj* os, size_t N, KeyFn keyFn)
{
    auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = keyFn(os[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Other changes to consider:

- Use a standard container, e.g. `vector` or `array` to house your Obj's,
- Consider passing iterators over the ranges rather than a pointer and a size,

Comment: `std::function` over template, why?

Comment: @mash *shrug* didn't seem to be worth introducing a template for this example.

Comment: Template is more appropriate for my use. I just gave a simplified model of the code so that I could get help in a timely manner. Thank you.

Comment: @LightyearBuzz Are the source arrays a fixed size? If so, you could consider http://ideone.com/PYzNSo or (returning a std::vector instead of passing in a fixed-sized array) http://ideone.com/igqqVB

Answer (score 1):

A possible transcription of your example in C++ could be:

```
#include <functional>
int* fun(Obj os[], std::function<int(Obj)> get_key, int N){
    int* a = new int[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        a[i] = get_key(os[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Use:

```
func(os, [](Obj obj){return obj.a;}, N);
```

You must declare a dynamic array because the size is variable. But with a raw pointer, you may obtain memory leak or segmentation fault. A version with managed pointers (only working in C++14):

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

std::unique_ptr<int[]> fun(Obj os[], std::function<int(Obj)> get_key, int N){
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> a = std::make_unique(N);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        a[i] = get_key(os[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Or with stl container (no memory allocation):

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

std::vector<int> fun(Obj os[], std::function<int(Obj)> get_key, int N){
    std::vector<int> a(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        a[i] = get_key(os[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

But it's often a bad idea to "translate" from one language to another ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using [range](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library you may simply do

```
for (int e : objs | ranges::v3::view::transform(&Obj::a)) {
    std::cout << e << " ";   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aba9125ac2bde622)